# How to install Syslinux on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: installation, 13.04, boot, bootloader, syslinux

I really searched a lot in Google, but i don't found anything. I want to replace my GRUB with Syslinux. I just installed syslinux with `sudo apt-get install syslinux` (alias, it seems it was already installed) but I don't know how to set it to be the bootloader. I tried `syslinux-install_update -ima` just like in Archlinux, but it failed. What can I do?

Another complementary question: How do I install Ubuntu 13.04 with Syslinux instead of GRUB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [ExtLinux](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=EXTLINUX), a variant of syslinux on Ubuntu 14.
You can find a very detailed installation guide [here](http://shallowsky.com/linux/extlinux.html).

A quick summary of the procedure:

1. Download the software:

   > sudo apt-get install extlinux syslinux-common
2. Install the bootloader:

   > sudo extlinux --install /boot/extlinux
3. Make sure the partion is marked as bootable using Gparted
4. Replace the GRUB2 MBR with the one used by extlinux:

   > sudo cat /usr/lib/extlinux/mbr.bin >/dev/sda
5. Setup the menu:

   > sudo cp -pv /usr/lib/syslinux/*menu* /boot/extlinux
6. Enable chain loading of Windows:

   > sudo cp -pv /usr/lib/syslinux/chain.c32 /boot/extlinux
7. Let ubuntu detect the OS's and built the menu

   > sudo extlinux-update
8. Reboot to test if it works.

Steps 5 and 6 maybe done automatically by extlinux-update.

Comment: Hi @tst, links can go down at any time, maybe you should put a short summary on what the guide says?

Answer (score -1):

sudo apt-get install syslinux

==> If you want to use syslinux as your bootloader

==> edit /boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg and run

==> # /usr/sbin/syslinux-install_update -i -a -m

==> to install it.

After running the script, you should receive a message advising you that Syslinux has been sucessfully installed on both drives:

Detected RAID on /boot - installing Syslinux with –raid

Syslinux install successful

Boot Flag Set - /dev/sda1

Boot Flag Set - /dev/sdb1

Installed MBR (/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin) to /dev/sda

Installed MBR (/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin) to /dev/sdb

Reboot

Source:
http://jasonwryan.com/blog/2012/07/09/syslinux/

Comment: `syslinux-install_update` simply doesn't exists on Ubuntu.